# How to make get request with multiple values for one form element

Tags: php, get, forms

I have a form, whose elements are drop down menus which you can select multiple values from.

For example:

```
<form class="ui form" id="filterImageForm" action="query.php">
    <div class="field" id="species" style="display: none;">
        <label>Species:</label>
        <select class="ui dropdown multiple" name="species" id="speciesSelect">
        <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="ui primary button">
</form>
```

These values are determined by the following code:

```
function populateSelect(selectName){

    // don't cache get request responses
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache : false });

    // form get request
    var data = "request="+selectName;

    // send get request to formFill.php which interacts with db
    $.getJSON("formFill.php", data, function(response){

    // select the select element
    var select = document.getElementById(selectName+'Select');

    // for each response from db, create new option for select and add the option to the select box
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    if (selectName == 'trapper' || selectName == 'trapper_site') {
        opt.innerHTML = response[i].option_id;
        opt.value = response[i].option_id;
    } else {
        opt.innerHTML = response[i].option_id + ' - ' + response[i].option_name;
        opt.value = response[i].option_id;


        select.appendChild(opt);
    }
});
```

Where formfill.php is a script that queries a database and echoes the result in an array.

So the form will have a list of species to select from as options.

On submit, the form is passed to query.php. However, if more than one species is selected, the url for the php page is something like: `http://localhost/query.php?species=Hedgehog&species=Rabbit`

How do I submit it so I can use both values, rather than the first value being overwritten by the second (in this case, if I echo `$_GET['species']` I get "Rabbit", and the 'Hedgehog' value is lost). Ideally I would have one get value containing an array of species.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should update your answer with a similar situation that is in your real project because as you put on the comment of my answer, it seems more complex that it seems on the question. I delete my answer to avoid confusions.

Comment: @Error404 Sorry for not giving a fuller question, I have updated it now and hopefully it is more clear.